# How to slowly show a ShaderEffect in QML?

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a `ShaderEffect` here with a red tint, and I want to enable/disable the shader with the click of a button. My background is green, so when the shader is enabled, I want to see a green color with the "Hello" text clearly visible. But from what I've tried, I cannot get there. Either the screen goes completely black when the shader is enabled, or the text is not visible. How can I enable the shader in a way where I see both the green color and the text?

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {

    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "green"
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Hello")
            font.pixelSize: 20
            color: "black"
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: rect
            onClicked: {
                if(shader.opacity > 0) {
                    shader.opacity = 0
                    shader.visible = false
                    console.log("Hiding")
                }
                else {
                    shader.opacity = 1
                    shader.visible = true
                    console.log("Showing")
                }
            }
        }

        ShaderEffect {
            id: shader
            anchors.fill: parent
            property variant source: rect
            Behavior on opacity { PropertyAnimation {} }
            visible: false
            opacity: 0
            fragmentShader: "
                            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                            uniform sampler2D source;
                            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                            void main() {
                                gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
                            }"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some adjustments to your code mainly the nesting that wasn't clear to me. But your issue is that you multiply green `vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)` with red `vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` which results in black `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. This applies also for the font color, black * red = black.

I also needed to add `layer.enabled: true` to the `Rectangle` in order to make it work.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "gray"
        layer.enabled: true

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Hello")
            font.pixelSize: 40
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (shader.opacity > 0) {
                shader.opacity = 0
                console.log("Hiding")
            } else {
                shader.opacity = 1
                console.log("Showing")
            }
        }
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id: shader
        anchors.fill: parent
        property variant source: rect
        Behavior on opacity { PropertyAnimation {} }
        opacity: 0
        fragmentShader: "
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            uniform sampler2D source;
            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
            }"
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Just so I understand, why do we need to add the layer.enabled line?

Comment: I think it is about drawing it into an offscreen buffer and enable the shader to grab it from there. Unfortunately I couldn't find a proper explanation.

Comment: I see. I imagine drawing on an offscreen buffer will be costly, especially if the base UI is complicated. Is there a way to achieve this without using layer.enabled? Perhaps using a ShaderEffectSource?

Comment: I would stick with [layer.enabled](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#layer.enabled-prop) instead of [ShaderEffectSource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffectsource.html#details) (read the note and warning), because it might actually be a performance improvement according to the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

ShaderEffect has changed and fragmentShader is now a URL and not longer an string.

From the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html#details

*In Qt 5, effects were provided in form of GLSL (OpenGL Shading Language) source code, often embedded as strings into QML. Starting with Qt 5.8, referring to files, either local ones or in the Qt resource system, became possible as well. In Qt 6, Qt Quick has support for graphics APIs, such as Vulkan, Metal, and Direct3D 11 as well. Therefore, **working with GLSL source strings is no longer feasible.***

So you have to change the fragmentShader property to a link to a *.qsb file.

Have a look at the Qt Shader Tools to get more details about the new shader infrastructure.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtshadertools-index.html

Comment: His import version `2.15` shows that he is using [Qt 5.15](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-shadereffect.html), so inline shaders are still supported, No need to use Qt Shader Tools in this case.